# SingalR connection and jQuery cohesion

Tags: jquery, signalr

Why does the signalr project choose to extend jquery with their connection?

Surely there is a reason, i just wanna know. :)

```
$.connection.hub.start();
```

could instead be

```
var connection = signalr.createConnection();
connection.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today signalr is a jquery plugin because it uses components of jquery including:

- Deferred
- Events
- Ajax

There is a workitem to decouple SignalR from jQuery but it's not very high on the list of priorities at the moment.

Comment: Thanks. I understand why it requires jquery, but why should jquery hold the connection?

Comment: It's a jQuery plugin. $.connection is an alias for $.signalR which is our root object.